# Having trouble converting code from Python to c#

Tags: python, c#, numpy, opencv

SOLVED: I'm working on detecting the MRZ of a passport.  I've got a strategy but due to lack of documentation I haven't been able to convert the following lines of code.  My project is using OpenCvSharp and NumSharp which is a port of numpy to c#.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Python Code:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# smooth the image using a 3x3 Gaussian, then apply the blackhat
# morphological operator to find dark regions on a light background
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3, 3), 0)
blackhat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_BLACKHAT, rectKernel)

# compute the Scharr gradient of the blackhat image and scale the
# result into the range [0, 255]
gradX = cv2.Sobel(blackhat, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)
gradX = np.absolute(gradX)
(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(gradX), np.max(gradX))
gradX = (255 * ((gradX - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal))).astype("uint8")
```

C# Code:

```
// smooth the image using a 3x3 Gaussian, then apply the blackhat
// morphological operator to find dark regions on a light background
smallImage = smallImage.GaussianBlur(new Size(3, 3), 0);
Cv2.MorphologyEx(smallImage, blackhat, MorphTypes.BlackHat, rectKernel);
```

// compute the Scharr gradient of the blackhat image and scale the
            // result into the range [0, 255]
            Cv2.Sobel(blackhat, gradX, MatType.CV_32F, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0);

```
        //(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(gradX), np.max(gradX))
        double minVal, maxVal;
        gradX.MinMaxLoc(out minVal, out maxVal);

        //gradX = (255 * ((gradX - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal))).astype("uint8")
        gradX.ConvertTo(gradX, MatType.CV_8U, 255.0 / (maxVal - minVal), -255.0 / minVal);
```

Specifically I'm having trouble with the last line of Python code. I'm not sure how to perform that calculation in c#.  I'm also not sure if I'm getting the `minVal` and `maxVal` values correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution to my original problem:

```
// compute the Scharr gradient of the blackhat image and scale the
// result into the range [0, 255]
Cv2.Sobel(blackhat, gradX, MatType.CV_32F, 1, 0, -1, 1, 0);

//(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(gradX), np.max(gradX))
double minVal, maxVal;
gradX.MinMaxLoc(out minVal, out maxVal);

//gradX = (255 * ((gradX - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal))).astype("uint8")
gradX.ConvertTo(gradX, MatType.CV_8U, 255.0 / (maxVal - minVal), -255.0 / minVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

An 8-bit unsigned integer is a `byte` in C#. You can do this:

```
var gradX = Convert.ToByte(255 * ((gradX - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal)));
```

I'm not sure what those min and max functions are doing, so I can't help there.

Comment: Hmm.. a valid point.. but in this case I am manipulating arrays.  All the more reason this is confusing.  That line of code is supposed to be normalizing an array that represents an image.  I'll try to provide more details on the context of this code, but the original post is here:

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/30/detecting-machine-readable-zones-in-passport-images/

Comment: Are you saying that `gradX`, `minVal` and/or `maxVal` are arrays?

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I figured it out.. I've updated the code above to reflect the solution.  Thank you!